# Custom function not recognized

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I created  anew function in sheets from within a sheet. The function is not recognized:

1. From within the sheet tools > script editor
2. ```
   function DOUBLE(input) {
     return input * 2;
   }
   ```
3. save
4. Go into the sheet, enter a cell and type `=double(10)`
5. Error "unknown function 'double'"

Comment: More info. I'm on the new version of sheets if that makes a difference. Also I have two scripts attached to the sheet.

Comment: Can you share your spreadsheet ?

Comment: I don't understand why there is a slash in. "unknown function 'double/'". Have you tried retyping your formula in a few other cells? Not copy and paste but retyping.

Comment: Hi @ScampMichael I opened the sheet again just now. For another reason I had cleared by browsers cookies about an hour ago. The custom functions are now working as expected. Don;t understand why they did not before I have not changed anything else, cookies must have been it. The backslash was a typo on my part

Comment: I had this issue and I realized it was because I was editing a sheet with my work identity, but every time I opened the script editor, it opened with my personal identity and so I was saving my script in the wrong place. Unfortunately, trying to switch identities in the script editor led to a "you must request permission...request not sent—would you like to request permission?" loop. Opening the sheet and the script editor in an incognito window solved this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clearing my cookies seemed to do the trick. Not sure if that qualifies as an answer but if anyone else comes across this post I hope that helps.

Comment: Had the same problem and hard refresh + clearing cache fixed it. Thanks!